# How to limit a GPT chatbot in specific domain?

Tags: finetuning, chatbot

When we are going to fine-tune a GPT-3 model for Q&A in specific domain, how we can avoid it to answer the questions from the other domains?
Suppose out chatbot is to answer to questions from trading area so, if someone asks him a question from political area, it should avoid to answer the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can just include a clause in the prompt, before providing the user question, to make it kindly refuse to answer questions not related to the target domain.